# DetailsView ItemCommand Index outside the bounds of the array

Tags: vb.net

I have the following DetailsView defined with a DropDownList of data and an Add ButtonField:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dvNewEntry" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="800px" 
      AutoGenerateRows="False" CssClass="gv_footer" BorderColor="Black" 
      BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="8">
<FieldHeaderStyle CssClass="th_right"  />
<Fields>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Account Name">
     <ItemTemplate> 
     <asp:Label ID="lblNewAcct" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ACCT_LIST") %         
     >'></asp:Label> 
     </ItemTemplate> 
     <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddAcctList" runat="server" DataSourceID="LUWAcctList"    
        DataTextField="ACCT_LIST" DataValueField="ACCT_LIST"
        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ACCT_LIST") %>' Font-Size="Small" Width="600">
        </asp:DropDownList>
     </InsertItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Save" CommandName="Add"/>
</Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

In the codebehind - I have the following ItemCommand sub.

```
Protected Sub dvNewEntry_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DetailsViewCommandEventArgs) Handles dvNewEntry.ItemCommand

    If e.CommandName = "Add" Then
        Dim newA As String
        newA = Trim(CType(dvNewEntry.FindControl("ddAcctList"), DropDownList).Text)
        etc. etc.
```

Everything works fine when the user selects a value from the dropdown list.  But if they don't make a selection and click the Add button - I get the following error when I land on the "If e.CommandName = Add" line:

**Index was outside the bounds of the array**

How do I handle this exception? Thanks

Comment: debug the code with a breakpoint on `If e.CommandName = "Add" Then`, inspect what the properties of e are and you'll see what the difference is in each case, then put in logic in to catch that case,  something like: If (e.[someproperty] IsNot Null) Then --> your code. Sorry my vb is rusty!

Comment: Thanks Tanner - I was able to capture the null property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If (e.[someproperty] IsNot Null) Then --> your code solved the problem.  Thanks Tanner